# minimize sum while minimizing difference

Tags: algorithm, mathematical-optimization, min

I want to find node (say index `i`) to satisfy following two criteria simultaneously:

1. minimize the sum of distances from node `A` to node `i`, say `d(A,i)`, and from node `i` to node `B`, say `d(i,B)`, i.e., `min  d(A,i)+d(i,B)`
2. minimize the difference between those distances, i.e., `min  |d(A,i)-d(i,B)|`.

Probably this is a well-known problem, but I could not find any reference which develops a suitable algorithm.

Comment: [Multi-objective optimization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-objective_optimization) is a well-established field. The precise way to model your problem depends on the details. E.g. depends on what is variable in the problem, and how trade-offs in the objectives should be treated.

Comment: Adding to @ErwinKalvelagen's comment, to state it bluntly, there may be no such `i` that the two differences are at their minimums **simultaneously**. So, the first thing to do is to explicitly state what to do in that case.

Comment: If their minimums would always match simultaneously, you would only have to find one of them.

Answer (score 2):

Compute distance for A to all other nodes, then compute the distance from B to all other nodes in the inverse graph (if your graph is not directed, then it's in the original graph).

You can run bellman ford O(VE) or Dijkstra (ElogV).

Then iterate over each node, you have d(A,i) and d(B,i) computed so pick the one that satisfies your criteria, sound like you should prefer `min d(A,i)+d(i,B)` over `min|d(A,i) - d(i,B)|`. In any case you will have all the values so you just need to pick the one you want. This will be O(V).

So overall your solution will be O(ElogV) assuming you do it with Dijkstra.